# MongoDB .NET Driver: Grouping with first accumulator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Is it possible to group with the $first accumulator in the aggregate pipeline using the .NET Driver 2.2?

I am trying to write the following query using the driver:

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
    [ 
        {
            $sort : { "createdDate" : -1 }
        },
        { 
            $group : { 
                _id : "$key",
                latestEntity : { $first : "$$ROOT" }
            }            
        }
    ]
```

.NET:

```
var result = collection
                .Aggregate()
                .SortByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
                .Group(k => k.Key, x => x.First())
                .ToList();
```

A `System.NotSupportException` is thrown with a "Specified method is not supported".

Comment: There currently isn't support for the $$ROOT special variable... If you'd like that, please file a feature request at jira.mongodb.org under the CSHARP project.